# How to view webpage in browser while using virtual machine?

Tags: node.js, browser, virtual-machine

I am sshed into a virtual machine where I am creating an application (I cannot on my local machine for no admin access). I wish to see the code when I run localhost:8080; how can I get some form of browser access to render this page while I am on a vm?

Comment: Did you try `http://<server_ip>:8080`? Of course if port 8080 is opened on server.

Comment: woops, I hadn't. Thanks!